# Running a Batch File in the Same Directory from the VBS

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, runtime-error

I have a VBScript that is supposed to run a .bat or .vbs file, but it doesn't work!
It comes up with an error saying that the file could not be found, whether i put in a file path or not (it shouldn't matter anyway I think because it's in the same directory).

So my question is, how do I start a .bat file (or even better, a .vbs file) from within a VBScript?

The relevant code is bellow:

```
'*******This is the start of my open command that doesn't work*******
Do
    If Hour(Now) >= 9 And Hour(Now) <= 18 And Minute(Now) = 34 And Second(Now) = 59 Then
        Dim shell
        Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        shell.Run "F:\\EAS\Volume Up.vbs"
        Set shell = Nothing
        MsgBox "My De-bug Message Box which doesn' even get to open"
        WScript.Sleep 2000
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        music = "C:\...\MYFILE.wav"
        WshShell.Run "wmplayer """ & music & """", 0, True
        WScript.Quit 1
    Else
'*******This is the end*******
```

So what am I doing wrong? Is it the wrong way to open it? What should I put instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be good to see the contents of the .BAT File.

Your code seems fine as I am able to run the below script on my machine:

```
   dim shell
   set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
   shell.run "tester.bat"
```

You may not see what the .BAT File is doing as it happens so quickly, as a tester add the following command to the end of your .BAT Script:

```
pause
```

Then you will see the command prompt open. As per my VB code above, the .BAT file contents are below:

```
@echo OFF
@echo %time%
pause
```

This will show you the current time and then pause, leaving the command prompt open. Give this a go as a tester as it works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I should have given more detail in my initial response, an error actually comes up in the running of the file saying that the file could not be found. The names are typed correctly. If this helps, I did a test to open a normal .txt file instead, which worked, unlike the .bat and .vbs files.
@Sudhir

Comment: Also, it shows the following error when I run it:

    Script:     F:\...\test.vbs
    Line:       3
    Error:      The system cannot find the file specified.
    Code:       80070002
    Source:     (null)

Comment: I was also getting this error: make sure that you add extra quotes around the path if the path contains spaces!!!

Answer (score 1):

putting triple quotes (as suggested by ToThePoint) around the path solved my vbs file error, where it was failed to find the file on specified path as file path was having spaces, like
D:\Main\My text Files\abc.txt.
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can think of is that it must be a typo in the file name.
Can you ensure the file name is spelled correct?
Or else please post the exact error you get.

Comment: Also, it shows the following error when I run it:

    Script:     F:\...\test.vbs
    Line:       3
    Error:      The system cannot find the file specified.
    Code:       80070002
    Source:     (null)

Comment: Try to quote the path, like: `shell.run """F:\\EAS\Volume Up.vbs"""`

Comment: It still comes up with that error, if it helps, this file is on a USB (is currently denoted as F:\\) and I have updated the sample of code to show more of the code in case that helps